# How to force recyclerView to not draw all of the elements at once, even when its inside an scroll view

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-viewpager

I checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53697474/4977669), and understood that `recyclerView` inside `scrollView` creates issues. But in my use case, i have to use `recyclerView` inside an `scrollView`

and i am facing the same issue, on activity start it tries to create layout for all of the item, and it freezes the UI.

I need to know if there is some way to restrict recyclerView to load specific number of item at a time.

Comment: You never, ever **have** to use a `RecyclerView` in a `ScrollView`. There's even [whole APIs](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/merge-adapters-sequentially-with-mergeadapter-294d2942127a) dedicated to letting you put headers and footers on your `RecyclerView`.

Comment: I am trying to implement bracketView, which can only be possible with nested scrollView, check following on github.
https://github.com/Emil333/TournamentBrackets